# How to create all possible combinations with splitted items in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have  data as in below delimited format

```
data - '1A,2B,2A'
```

expected output - is the combination with each element and the element itself

```
OrderId combination
    1   1A,2B
    2   1A,2A
    3   2B,1A
    4   2B,2A
    5   2A,1A
    6   2A,2B
    7   1A
    8   2B
    9   2A
```

I am trying by splitting the data into different items  as below

```
    DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100);    
    SET @data = '1A,2B,2A   

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE
            (
             OrderId INT IDENTITY,             
             Combo VARCHAR(10)
            );

--insert  data to a table
        INSERT  INTO @Temp
               SELECT 
               Split.temp.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') combination
              FROM    ( SELECT    CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(@data, ',',
                                                      '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS String
                      ) AS temp
                      CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split ( temp );
```

any idea how we can create combination with splitted items?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your data limited to three parts, or can it be more?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock it can be more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your SQL.  @data had no closing "'", and you have the wrong separator in your split function ('|' instead of ',').

Once you have the split values, you can simply get the combinations by a self cross join, where the split data doesn't match.  Finally get your orderid based on length and value.  Something like this should get the results you need, without the need for a cursor.

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100);    
SET @data = '1A,2B,2A,3C'   

DECLARE @temp TABLE (splitdata varchar(5))
INSERT INTO @temp(splitdata)
SELECT Split.temp.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') combination
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@data, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) AS temp
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(temp);


INSERT INTO @temp(splitdata)
SELECT t1.splitdata + ',' + t2.splitdata FROM @temp t1
CROSS JOIN @temp t2 WHERE t1.splitdata <> t2.splitdata

DECLARE @result TABLE (orderid int identity(1, 1), combo varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @result (combo)
SELECT splitdata 
FROM @temp
ORDER BY (LEN(splitdata)) DESC, splitdata

SELECT * from @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100);    
SET @data = '1A,2B,2A'

DECLARE @value VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @value2 VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id = 1;

DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    OrderId INT,             
    Combo VARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT value FROM string_split(@data,',')
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE db_cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT value FROM string_split(@data,',') WHERE value <> @value
    OPEN db_cursor2
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @value2
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Temp(OrderId,Combo)
        SELECT @id, @value + ','+ @value2
        SET @id = @id + 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor2 INTO @value2
    END
    CLOSE db_cursor2
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor2

    INSERT INTO @Temp(OrderId,Combo)
    SELECT @id, @value
    SET @id = @id + 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM @temp
```